# Using the Python Keras multi_gpu_model with LSTM / GRU to predict Timeseries data

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, lstm, gpu

I'm having an issue with python keras LSTM / GRU layers with `multi_gpu_model` for machine learning.

When I use a single GPU, the predictions work correctly matching the sinusoidal data in the script below. See image labeled "1 GPUs".

[image: Using 1 GPU]

When I use multiple GPUs, the inverse transforms of both the training and test data return results that cluster around the lows of the original data  See image labeled "4 GPUs".

[image: Using 4 GPUs]

Is this:

1. a bug?
2. a case where I'm missing a multiplier that should be used
   when `multi_gpu_model` is used?
3. an example where the
   `multi_gpu_model` documentation isn't complete with a
   caveat to cover this specific case.
4. the result of flaw(s) in my code?

---

Versions

```
Keras                   2.2.4  
Keras-Applications      1.0.6  
Keras-Preprocessing     1.0.5  
tensorboard             1.12.0 
tensorflow-gpu          1.12.0
```

GPUs

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.79       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   42C    P0    36W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   48C    P0    37W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:41:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 34%   44C    P0    34W / 180W |      0MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:42:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 31%   42C    P0    32W / 180W |      0MiB /  8112MiB |      5%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""LSTM for sinusoidal data problem with regression framing.

Based on:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

"""

# Standard imports
import argparse
import math

# PIP3 imports
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model

import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

def main():
    # fix random seed for reproducibility
    numpy.random.seed(7)

    # Get CLI arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--gpus',
        help='Number of GPUs to use.',
        type=int, default=1)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    gpus = args.gpus

    # load the dataset
    dataframe = DataFrame(
        [0.00000, 5.99000, 11.92016, 17.73121, 23.36510, 28.76553, 33.87855,
         38.65306, 43.04137, 46.99961, 50.48826, 53.47244, 55.92235, 57.81349,
         59.12698, 59.84970, 59.97442, 59.49989, 58.43086, 56.77801, 54.55785,
         51.79256, 48.50978, 44.74231, 40.52779, 35.90833, 30.93008, 25.64279,
         20.09929, 14.35496, 8.46720, 2.49484, -3.50245, -9.46474, -15.33247,
         -21.04699, -26.55123, -31.79017, -36.71147, -41.26597, -45.40815,
         -49.09663, -52.29455, -54.96996, -57.09612, -58.65181, -59.62146,
         -59.99540, -59.76988, -58.94716, -57.53546, -55.54888, -53.00728,
         -49.93605, -46.36587, -42.33242, -37.87600, -33.04113, -27.87613,
         -22.43260, -16.76493, -10.92975, -4.98536, 1.00883, 6.99295, 12.90720,
         18.69248, 24.29100, 29.64680, 34.70639, 39.41920, 43.73814, 47.62007,
         51.02620, 53.92249, 56.28000, 58.07518, 59.29009, 59.91260, 59.93648,
         59.36149, 58.19339, 56.44383, 54.13031, 51.27593, 47.90923, 44.06383,
         39.77815, 35.09503, 30.06125, 24.72711, 19.14590, 13.37339, 7.46727,
         1.48653, -4.50907, -10.45961, -16.30564, -21.98875, -27.45215,
         -32.64127, -37.50424, -41.99248, -46.06115, -49.66959, -52.78175,
         -55.36653, -57.39810, -58.85617, -59.72618, -59.99941, -59.67316,
         -58.75066, -57.24115, -55.15971, -52.52713, -49.36972, -45.71902,
         -41.61151, -37.08823, -32.19438, -26.97885, -21.49376, -15.79391,
         -9.93625, -3.97931, 2.01738, 7.99392, 13.89059, 19.64847, 25.21002,
         30.51969, 35.52441, 40.17419, 44.42255, 48.22707, 51.54971, 54.35728,
         56.62174, 58.32045, 59.43644, 59.95856, 59.88160, 59.20632, 57.93947,
         56.09370, 53.68747, 50.74481, 47.29512, 43.37288, 39.01727, 34.27181,
         29.18392, 23.80443, 18.18710, 12.38805, 6.46522, 0.47779, -5.51441,
         -11.45151])
    dataset = dataframe.values
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

    # normalize the dataset
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

    # split into train and test sets
    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size:len(dataset), :]

    # reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
    look_back = 1
    trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
    testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

    # reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
    trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
    testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

    # create and fit the LSTM network
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        serial_model = Sequential()
    serial_model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
    serial_model.add(Dense(1))
    if gpus == 1:
        parallel_model = serial_model
    else:
        parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(
            serial_model,
            cpu_relocation=True,
            gpus=gpus)
    parallel_model.compile(
        loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    parallel_model.fit(
        trainX, trainY,
        epochs=100,
        batch_size=int(dataset.size * gpus / 20),
        verbose=2)

    # make predictions
    if gpus == 1:
        trainPredict = parallel_model.predict(trainX)
        testPredict = parallel_model.predict(testX)
    else:
        trainPredict = serial_model.predict(trainX)
        testPredict = serial_model.predict(testX)

    # invert predictions
    trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
    trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
    testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
    testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])

    # calculate root mean squared error
    trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:, 0]))
    print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
    testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:, 0]))
    print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

    # shift train predictions for plotting
    trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
    trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
    trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict

    # shift test predictions for plotting
    testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
    testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
    testPredictPlot[
        len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict

    # plot baseline and predictions
    plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset), label='Complete Data')
    plt.plot(trainPredictPlot, label='Training Data')
    plt.plot(testPredictPlot, label='Prediction Data')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.title('Using {} GPUs'.format(gpus))
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I thought it may have something to do with the Sequential model, but I get the same results when I replace:

```
# create and fit the LSTM network
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    serial_model = Sequential()
serial_model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
serial_model.add(Dense(1))
```

with:

```
from keras import Model, Input

# Create layers for model
x_tensor = Input(shape=(1, look_back))
layer_1 = LSTM(4)(x_tensor)
y_tensor = Dense(1)(layer_1)

# Create and fit the LSTM network
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    serial_model = Model(inputs=x_tensor, outputs=y_tensor)
```

I now think it has something to do with the way `multi_gpu_model` splits the timeseries data across the GPUs. The RMSE error rates are noticeably different.

**RMSE - I GPU**

```
Train Score: 4.49 RMSE
Test Score: 4.79 RMSE
```

**RMSE - 4 GPUs**

```
Train Score: 76.54 RMSE
Test Score: 77.55 RMSE
```

Comment: I've opened a case with the Keras team which hopefully will resolve the issue https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11953